# Pymysql execute sql-sump

Tags: python, pymysql

I have mysql dump file that I want to import into my database. I tried using Pymysql package. However it only let's me to execute one statement and fails to execute other statements.

I use the following syntax:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=usr, passwd=password, db=event["db_name"],  connect_timeout=5)
sql_dump = open('files/fcpdb.sql', 'r').read()

    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(sql_dump)
```